# Selecting only certain data values to view from a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgDkl.png)

I have created a data frame with the following codes:

```
casualty <- Full %>% count(Casualty_Type,Year) %>% group_by(Year)
```

`Casualty_Type` column has a couple of values (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 19, 30). As I want to create a stacked bar chart presenting how many times do 1, 2, and 9 appear each year, I only want to show these values in the new data frame. So, I want to hide the other values in the new data frame.

Can someone help me with this?

```
casualty <- Full %>% 
  count(Casualty_Type,Year) %>% 
  group_by(Year) --> code for the current grouping
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data?

Comment: If you want only include some of the values in `Causalty_Type` then you could add a `filter(Causalty_Type %in% c(1, 2, 9))` before or after `count`.

Comment: @TomHoel I have added a data sample

Comment: An image is not a sample of your data. Use `dput()` function with a subset of `Full` with the minimal number of rows to reproduce your problem. And paste in your post the output from `dput()`

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg